# T-SQL Function Taking Different Forms

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to have one function which will be able to take different forms:

```
a. to calculate values between two numbers; 
b. to calculate values greater than 20; 
c. to calculate values less than 20;
```

using the same function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION CalcBetween(@from int, @to int, @date date) RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
(
SELECT  isnull(T50.Amnt,0) as 'Amnt'
        ,T50.Code as 'Code'
FROM table as t00
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   (
   SELECT T51.Name as 'Code', sum(T51.deb-T51.cred) as 'Amnt'
   FROM table1 as T51
   INNER JOIN table as T52
     on T51.Name = T52.Code
   WHERE T51.RefDate <= @date
     and **DATEDIFF(d, T51.DueDate, @date) between @from and @to**
     --or DATEDIFF(d, T51.DueDate, @date) > 20
     --or DATEDIFF(d, T51.DueDate, @date) < 20
   GROUP BY T51.Name
   ) T50 
 on T50.Code = t00.Code  
); 
GO
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like valid syntax according to Docs: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214485(v=sql.80).aspx  Does this compile as is or are you getting an error?  Additionally some sample data with expected output table would help.

Comment: It compiles as is. Obviously without the asterixes before/after DATEDIFF(d, T51.DueDate, (at)date) between (at)from and (at)to

Comment: Do you want all 3 forms returned with one call, or are you passing in the form you want? If its the latter, how do you tell which form you want to run?

Comment: I was thinking I'd pass 4 parameters: from, to, date, unbounded (boolean). By unbounded I mean that either there are two values (between x and y){bounded} or <20 / >20{unbounded}. However since SQL is unlike formal languages like java(using several if statements) I don't know how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets define the parameters for each behavior:

- To calculate values between two days, `@from` and `@to` are both not null. For example: `CalcBetween(10, 40, '2014-08-28 00:00:00.000')`
- To calculate values greater than 20 days, `@from = 20` and `@to = NULL`. For example: `CalcBetween(20, NULL, '2014-08-28 00:00:00.000')`
- To calculate values less than 20 days, `@from = NULL` and `@to = 20`. For example: `CalcBetween(NULL, 20, '2014-08-28 00:00:00.000')`

In this way, the function can be:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CalcBetween(@from int, @to int, @date date) RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
  SELECT isnull(T50.Amnt,0) as 'Amnt'
     ,T50.Code as 'Code'
  FROM table as t00
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
      SELECT T51.Name as 'Code', sum(T51.deb-T51.cred) as 'Amnt'
      FROM table1 as T51
        INNER JOIN table as T52
          on T51.Name = T52.Code
      WHERE T51.RefDate <= @date AND
      (
        (@from IS NOT NULL AND @to IS NOT NULL AND DATEDIFF(d, T51.DueDate, @date) between ISNULL(@from,0) and ISNULL(@to,0))
        OR
        (@from IS NOT NULL AND @to IS NULL AND DATEDIFF(d, T51.DueDate, @date) > @from)
        OR
        (@from IS NULL AND @to IS NOT NULL AND DATEDIFF(d, T51.DueDate, @date) < @to)
      )
      GROUP BY T51.Name
    ) T50 
    on T50.Code = t00.Code  
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do it this way... I don't quite understand your 4 parameters system. But I think you could take this and mod it pretty easily. If I'm incorrect, and you want 3 sum columns back, it's also pretty easy to break up the one column into the 3 individual sum forms. (The @form variable is a placeholder for your 4th parameter.)

```
CREATE FUNCTION CalcBetween(@from int, @to int, @date date) RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
(
SELECT  isnull(T50.Amnt,0) as 'Amnt'
        ,T50.Code as 'Code'
FROM table as t00
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   (
   SELECT T51.Name as 'Code'
      , sum(Case 
                when DATEDIFF(d, T51.DueDate, @date) between @from and @to and @form=1 then T51.deb-T51.cred 
                when DATEDIFF(d, T51.DueDate, @date) < 20 and @form=2 then T51.deb-T51.cred
                when DATEDIFF(d, T51.DueDate, @date) > 20 and @form=3 then T51.deb-T51.cred  
                else 0 end
            ) as 'Amnt'
   FROM table1 as T51
   INNER JOIN table as T52
     on T51.Name = T52.Code
   WHERE T51.RefDate <= @date
   GROUP BY T51.Name
   ) T50 
 on T50.Code = t00.Code  
);
```